# How to write this Regular Expression

Tags: regex

How do i write a regular expression which accepts only  value "1"  in the textbox 
and it should not accept zero or greter than "1"

Comment: Why have a textbox if it can accept only one value anyway? Why not a checkbox?

Comment: Why on earth would you use a regex for this?  Aside from the complexity associated with actually writing the regex, invoking the regex engine is incredibly expensive compared to a simple integer comparison in any language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^1$/
```

… but for a "Must be this value, exactly this value, and nothing but this value" test, you would be much better off with a simple string comparison.

Comment: How do i add This to the existing one ^[0-9\ ]+$  to this and form the expression  /^1$/

Comment: There is one problem But i cannot explain and it is solved now

Answer (score 8):

```
if (theTextBoxValue == "1") {
   // accept
} else {
  // reject
}
```

You don't need regex for this simple task. And, if you only accept "1" in a user input, why provide such an input to the user at all?

Answer (score 1):

`/^1$/` but a simple `== "1"` will be enough in most languages (or `.equals("1")`).

Answer (score 1):

I saw your previous question (using the jquery validationEngine), and I was intrigued by it so I started looking.

The problem with using a funcCall (as you were trying in the old post) is that the function is called without any context (has no arguments, and has this == window), so you can't tell which input field is being validated.(I solved this with a trick - see example & comments linked below).

Another solution I found was using regex(as you are trying now). 
This is the entry you have to add to the languages file:

```
"isOne":{
        "regex":"/^1$/",
        "alertText":"* Only '1' is valid [regex]"
    }
```

This is how you use it on the input field:

```
<input type="text" class="validate[custom[isOne]]">
```

And this is how you start the validation engine:

```
$('#form').validationEngine({
    validationEventTriggers:"change"
});
```

You can view a working example using both function and regex [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/x7g5q/)

Comment: At Least you understand my problem So i opted for Regex and was able to solve it easliy

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you want to use regex for this.

Pattern: `^1$`